# How does this function get executed without being called

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am extremely new to programming. I don't understand how this function is executed without being called. We haven't called any function here but we receive output. How is this so?

```
let eightGb = phones.filter(function(item, i){
    if(item.ram == '8gb')
        return item;
})
console.log(eightGb)
```

Comment: You're talking about the `function(item, i){`? `filter` calls that.

Comment: Hey @Arpit7, it would do you a lot of good if you ran through a book to get the basics right. There's also a huge batch of excellent, free content available online(https://javascript.info/, https://www.w3schools.com/js/ for example). Good luck.

Comment: Don't use w3schools, it's got broad but shallow and sometimes incorrect coverage. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) is a collaboratively-edited, ad-free, well-respected resource.

Answer (score 2):

That code **is** calling a function, it's calling the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of `phones`, which is presumably an array. (Methods are functions.) The `filter` method, in turn, calls the function you pass into it (a "callback") for each entry in the array. `filter` builds a new array that only contains the entries of the original array that the callback returned a truthy value for. So if `phones` has, for instance, 12 items in it, then the callback will get called 12 times: once for each item. That code is building a new array only containing the items that have `ram == '8gb'`.

---

A bit of a side note, but that particular code is a bit misleading, because it returns `item` rather than `true`. The return value of a `filter` callback is a flag. That callback could be better written like this:

```
let eightGb = phones.filter(function(item) {
    return item.ram == '8gb';
});
console.log(eightGb);
```

or as a concise [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), with parameter [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
let eightGb = phones.filter(({ram}) => ram == '8gb');
console.log(eightGb);
```